# Spring: How to inject a bean from another project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I have two packages com.a.b.c and com.x.y.z. In com.a.b.c, I've defined a component like this:

```
@Named
public class MyClass
{
    @Inject
    public MyClass()
    {
    }
}
```

In com.x.y.z, I have a class where I want to inject MyClassA like this:

```
public class MyOtherClass
{
     @Inject
     private MyClass myClass;
}
```

What configuration changes do I need to make so that I can inject MyClass into MyOtherClass? Right now I get the build error

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.a.b.c.MyClass] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should specify necessary packages in @ComponentScan annotation above your Spring Configuration class

Answer (score 2):

Specify the package name in component-scan to initialize the bean.

XML config

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.a.b.c" />
```

Java configuration class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.a.b.c", "com.x.y.z"})
class AppConfig{
}
```